# Change image source of Rectangle everytime I move the joystick

Tags: python, kivy

I built my own Joystick in Kivy and whenever I move it the character moves as well. I wanted it so that the source image of the Rectangle (The character) changes whenever I move and make it look like its walking but in this code it only changes when I put the joystick in a certain direction. Is it possible to make it?

Also 1 more problem, I want to make the character still moving as long as the joystick is on the edge, in this code it stops whenever I stop moving the joystick as well.

Heres *main.py*

```
class Controller(Widget):
    control = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
             self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(300, 300), size=(50, 50))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        addx = int(touch.x)-50
        addy = int(touch.y)-50
        print(str(addx) + " " + str(addy))
        self.control.size = 95, 95
        if addx >= 90:
            addx = 90
        if addy >= 90:
            addy = 90
        if addx <= 10:
            addx = 10
        if addy <= 10:
            addy = 10

        if addx > 50:
            self.rect.pos = self.rect.pos[0] + 2, self.rect.pos[1]
            self.rect.source = "assets/faceleft_rightfootinfront.png"
        if addy > 50:
            self.rect.pos = self.rect.pos[0], self.rect.pos[1] + 2
            self.rect.source = "assets/faceleft_leftfootinfront.png"
        if addx < 50:
            self.rect.pos = self.rect.pos[0] - 2, self.rect.pos[1]
            self.rect.source = "assets/faceright_leftfootinfront.png"
        if addy < 50:
            self.rect.pos = self.rect.pos[0], self.rect.pos[1] - 2
            self.rect.source = "assets/faceright_rightfootinfront.png"

        self.control.pos = addx, addy

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        pass     # Overriding so it doesnt turn blue

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        self.control.pos = (50, 50)    # Return to original position
        self.control.size = 100, 100
```

Heres *main.kv*

```
<Controller>
control: control
Button:
    id: control
    background_normal: "assets/controller.png"
    pos: 50, 50
<Character>
character: character
Rectangle:
    id: character
    size: 25, 25
    pos: 400, 400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.rect.source` is being changed twice with every mouse motion, so only the last change will have an effect. In your series of `if addx` and `if addy` conditions, two of them will be `True` every time. Perhaps a different code block determining the `self.rect.source` change would work better.

In order to get the motion to continue, you just need to use `Clock.schedule_interval()` to schedule continuous motion. Here is a modified version of your `Controller` class that does that:

```
class Controller(Widget):
    control = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sched = None

        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,0,0,1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(300, 300), size=(50, 50))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.sched is not None:   # cancel motion
            self.sched.cancel()
            self.sched = None
        addx = int(touch.x)-50
        addy = int(touch.y)-50
        print(str(addx) + " " + str(addy))
        self.control.size = 95, 95
        if addx >= 90:
            addx = 90
        if addy >= 90:
            addy = 90
        if addx <= 10:
            addx = 10
        if addy <= 10:
            addy = 10

        self.move_it(addx, addy, 0)  # without this the image will only move when mouse motion stops

        self.sched = Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.move_it, addx, addy), 0.05)

        self.control.pos = addx, addy

    def move_it(self, addx, addy, dt):
        if addx > 50:
            self.rect.pos = self.rect.pos[0] + 2, self.rect.pos[1]
            self.rect.source = "back.png"
        if addy > 50:
            self.rect.pos = self.rect.pos[0], self.rect.pos[1] + 2
            self.rect.source = "forward.png"
        if addx < 50:
            self.rect.pos = self.rect.pos[0] - 2, self.rect.pos[1]
            self.rect.source = "back.png"
        if addy < 50:
            self.rect.pos = self.rect.pos[0], self.rect.pos[1] - 2
            self.rect.source = "forward.png"

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        pass     # Overriding so it doesnt turn blue

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.sched is not None:   # cancel motion
            self.sched.cancel()
            self.sched = None
        self.control.pos = (50, 50)    # Return to original position
        self.control.size = 100, 100
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try figuring out how to make it look like walking.